# Navigation Bar Dropdown problems

Tags: html, css

I'm building a navigation bar and I want

- all the items on the same row [not sure why a 2nd row is created]
- the dropdown items from 'Samples' button to display vertically instead of horizontally

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/RadiantSilvergun/xsbnjo5g/5/

I've used `<div>` elements instead of `<ul>` and `<li>` elements, is that a problem?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropbutton {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font: 1em times;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: static;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content>a {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content>a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbutton {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.button {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  ;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <div><a href="#">Contact Me</a></div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbutton">Samples</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div><a href="#">Recommendations</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Video Editing</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Photoshop</a></div>
  <div><a style="float: right" href="#">About</a></div>
</div>
```